# How to use dropdownlist as autocomplete

Tags: vb.net

I have a combobox and the dropdown set to simple. The autocompletemode is set to append and autocompletesource to listitems. The dropdown items are retrieve from the sql server.
I want the autocomplete to use the dropdownlist but instead a new dropdown is used for the autocomplete. I want to be able to type something and the dropdownlist will correspond with what i type. For instead if i type 'a' all dropdown items starting with 'a' should be shown.
This is what i have tried in keypress events

```
Dim cb As ComboBox = CType(sender,ComboBox)
    If (Not e.Handled  _
        AndAlso (Not cb.DroppedDown  _
                 AndAlso ((e.KeyChar <> CType(Keys.Return,Char))  _
                          AndAlso (e.KeyChar <> CType(Keys.Escape,Char))))) Then
        If ((cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)  _
            AndAlso ((cb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest)  _
                     OrElse (cb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend))) Then
            cb.DroppedDown = true
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: where is your code? show what you try so far.

Comment: @MaximusDebois Pleasde do not add code to the comments [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47534146/edit) your question and add that code

Comment: You said you have AutoCompleteMode set to Append, yet you're checking for Suggest or SuggestAppend.  Try setting it to Suggest.

Comment: i tried that but a new dropdown is used but i want it to use the dropdown of the combobox